# blind passthrough has been deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, redis, sidekiq

I'm getting following warning at my console:

> > Passing 'connection' command to redis as is; blind passthrough has been deprecated and will be removed in redis-namespace 2.0 (at /home/tecorb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@mproj/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/web/helpers.rb:152:in `block in redis_connection')

I'm using following gems in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'sidekiq'
gem "sidekiq-cron", "~> 0.4.5"
gem 'sidekiq-status'
gem 'sidekiq-failures'
gem 'redis-namespace', '~> 1.5'
```

Please, let me know where I'm lacking the things?

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in redis-namespace.  Don't use namespaces.

https://github.com/resque/redis-namespace/issues/151

Comment: Is there any alternative for that?